# How to separate picture and label of a node with GraphViz?

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to display a graph with images and labels with GraphViz. I would like to display the label under the image (see `labelloc="b"` option on the graph) but somehow it doesn't not work. Label and image are overlapped.

Any idea what I am missing?

Below is the DOT code I am using, and the current result.

Thanks!

[image: VizGraph with 3 nodes, background images and labels]

```
digraph {
graph [compound=true, labelloc="b"];
node [shape=box];
edge [dir=none];

Label1[label="Label1",image="images/Avatar1.png"];
Label2[label="Label2",image="images/Avatar2.png"];
Label3[label="Label3",image="images/Avatar3.png"];

{ 
    rank=same;
    Label1 -> h0 -> Label2;
    h0[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
}
{
    h0_0;
    h0_0[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
}

h0 -> h0_0;
h0_0 -> Label3;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPD: You need just to add an [imagepos](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:imagepos) attribute to your solution with `height`:

```
digraph {
graph [compound=true, labelloc="b"];
node [shape=box];
edge [dir=none];

Label1[
    label="Label1"
    height="2.1"
    imagepos="tc"
    labelloc="b"
    image="images/Avatar1.png"
];
Label2[
    label="Label2"
    height="2.1"
    imagepos="tc"
    labelloc="b"
    image="images/Avatar2.png"
];
Label3[
    label="Label3"
    height="2.1"
    imagepos="tc"
    labelloc="b"
    image="images/Avatar3.png"
];

{ 
    rank=same;
    Label1 -> h0 -> Label2;
    h0[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
}
{
    h0_0;
    h0_0[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
}

h0 -> h0_0;
h0_0 -> Label3;
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Or you may also use [HTML-like labels](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/shapes.html#html), and specifically, tables:

```
digraph {
graph [compound=true, labelloc="b"];
node [shape=box];
edge [dir=none];

Label1 [
    shape=plain
    label=<
        <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellborder="1">
            <tr><td><img src="images/Avatar1.png" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Label1</td></tr>
        </table>
    >
];
Label2 [
    shape=plain
    label=<
        <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellborder="1">
            <tr><td><img src="images/Avatar2.png" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Label2</td></tr>
        </table>
    >
];
Label3 [
    shape=plain
    label=<
        <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellborder="1">
            <tr><td><img src="images/Avatar3.png" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Label3</td></tr>
        </table>
    >
];

{
    rank=same;
    Label1 -> h0 -> Label2;
    h0[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
}
{
    h0_0;
    h0_0[shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
}

h0 -> h0_0;
h0_0 -> Label3;
}
```

The code is a bit more complex (at first glance), but as a bonus you get more flexible control over the borders.
Result:

[image]

Comment: F.y.i: I am using GraphViz 2.28 (due to a different problem I cannot upgrade further at the moment). With 2.28, the "imagepos" solution doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying a "height" (warning, those are "inches") for the nodes, I get the "labelloc" to work and I can thus move the label out of the picture. I would prefer if the box didn't have that white place at the top, but it's better than before.

[image]